# I have setup a Email server with Postfix, Dovecot and MariaDB on CentOS 7, but got errors in the maillog, whats reason and how to fix?

Tags: postfix

I have setup a Email server with Postfix, Dovecot and MariaDB on CentOS 7, but got errors in the maillog, whats reason and how to fix?

errors messages:

```
May 14 01:51:27 localhost postfix/master[1798]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/proxymap: bad command startup -- throttling
May 14 01:51:27 localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[26968]: warning: private/proxymap socket: service dict_proxy_open: Success
May 14 01:51:27 localhost postfix/master[1798]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/proxymap pid 13088 exit status 1
May 14 01:52:27 localhost postfix/proxymap[13126]: fatal: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf: bad string length 0 < 1: table =
May 14 01:52:27 localhost postfix/proxymap[13127]: fatal: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf: bad string length 0 < 1: table =
```

Comment: what does it means for this sql? -->   SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1),'/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1),'/') FROM users WHERE email='%s'

Comment: fatal: /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf: bad string length 0 < 1: table : Empty file ?

Comment: @lewis.tao you can use postmap to test your config

Comment: Post full content of the `/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf` BUT be sure to change the password and username (so we don't see them)

Comment: it first time to post here, i even can't post code with <line break>

Comment: I used MariaDB, database is mail, the user table have a records as     support@mydomainc.com

Comment: the  /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
is following:       user = mail_admin
password = mypass
dbname = mail
Query = SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1),'/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1),'/') FROM users WHERE email='%s'
hosts = 127.0.0.1

Comment: Please see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://serverfault.com/help/formatting)

Comment: And missing table param in file ! http://www.postfix.org/MYSQL_README.html